# Is there a way to use scikit-learn StackingRegressor with pre-trained models?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two pre-trained scikit-learn models, `model_1` and `model_2` such that the output of `model_1` is input to `model_2`. For example:

```
some_input_data = np.random.rand(50, 3)
model_1_preds = model_1.predict(some_input_data)
model_1_preds = model_1_preds.reshape(-1, 1)
predictions = model_2.predict(model_1_preds)
```

I would like to stack (or chain) these two models using scikit-learn.

I tried `sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor` class, but I couldn't figure out how to use it with pretrained models.

If I try:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
stacked = StackingRegressor(estimators=[('model_1', model_1)], final_estimator=model_2)
stacked.predict(some_input_data)
```

I get the following error

`NotFittedError: This StackingRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.`

Is there a way to combine pre-trained models with `StackingRegressor` or alternatives such as `make_pipeline`?

Answer (score 1):

Using StackedRegressor, it looks like you can set the cv argument to “prefit” allowing you to use pretrained base estimators. You still need to fit the final estimator of the StackRegressor though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).